# How do I get rid of the images left of the code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Basically, how can I hide these icons that appear automatically when I get the ID of a drawable in Java code? Or at least limit their number to 1 instead of 5?

[image: picture]

I've looked everywhere in the settings and can't seem to find anything. And they are pretty annoying, as they take away quite a bit of coding space.

Comment: I think this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the icons by going to preferences -> Editor -> Appearance. There you will find a checkbox saying Show icons preview in gutter for small icons. (Java)

You can also disable css color previews there if you want. For the change to take effect I had to restart Android Studio.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, even after restarting. That option sounds like it's what I'm looking for though. So maybe it's just a bug with Android Studio..

Comment: Could be, it works on my version of Android Studio (0.5.8). You can file a bug report at http://tools.android.com/feedback

Comment: Same problem here on Android Studio 1.5 and none of these changes on this post has any effect on disappearing the icons or css color boxes from gutter.

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences -> Editor-> Appearance. Uncheck the box that says 
"Show CSS color preview icon in gutter"

[image]